# "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found" error for android studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to use [Bypass](https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass), an markdown library, for my android app. I have managed to implement it to my android project and be able to new the function. However, after I implemented the library and try to run it's function I received this error :

```
Process: com.test.ndktest, PID: 24196
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for in.uncod.android.bypass.Document in.uncod.android.bypass.Bypass.processMarkdown(java.lang.String) (tried Java_in_uncod_android_bypass_Bypass_processMarkdown and Java_in_uncod_android_bypass_Bypass_processMarkdown__Ljava_lang_String_2)
        at in.uncod.android.bypass.Bypass.processMarkdown(Native Method)
        at in.uncod.android.bypass.Bypass.markdownToSpannable(Bypass.java:88)
        at in.uncod.android.bypass.Bypass.markdownToSpannable(Bypass.java:84)
        at com.test.ndktest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

I have followed its [implement](http://uncodin.github.io/bypass/) instructions to import the project with NDK and boost library. (In android studio way )

thanks.

here's my main activity file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("bypass");
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Bypass bypass = new Bypass();
    String markdownString = "#Markdown!";

    CharSequence string = bypass.markdownToSpannable(markdownString);
    text.setText(string);

    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
//public native String getStringFromNative();
```

}

Comment: Why do you have `System.loadLibrary("bypass");` in your class? [The `Bypass` class](https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass/blob/master/platform/android/library/src/in/uncod/android/bypass/Bypass.java) already does this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have deleted the line, but the project still shows the same error.

Comment: And you're sure you've included the `in.uncod.android.bypass.Document` class in your build? And you didn't change the package name or anything? If you decompile your APK with [`apktool`](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), is the `Document` class present among the smali files?

Comment: I have imported the Bypass as module, so it should have included. right? or am i missing something?

Comment: Where was the native function `processMarkdown()` implemented?  Can we see that C++ code.